# dataframe group, sum and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe dfsorted :

```py
dfsorted = df.sort_values(["sku"], ascending=[True])
print(dfsorted.head())
```

| id | sku | bill | qty_left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 186 | 01-04 | 50469 | 0 |
| 16 | 01-20 | 50262 | 15 |
| 267 | 01-20 | 50460 | 1 |
| 18 | 01-20 | 50262 | 5 |
| 17 | 01-20 | 50262 | 5 |

How can I  group / aggregate the dfsorted into this desired result:

| sku | bill | qty_left |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-04 | 50469 | 0 |
| 01-20 | 50262, 50460 | 26 |

So :

- group the dataframe by 'sku'
- for each 'sku', concatenate the 'bill' values (these are already formatted as strings, I don't care if there are duplicates but unique values would be nice too)
- for each 'sku', sum the 'qty_left' values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `agg`, where you can apply both custom (`lambda`) functions as standard (such as `sum`) functions:

```
df.groupby('sku').agg({'bill': lambda x: set(x), 'qty_left':'sum'})
```

`set` makes sure they are unique values, using `list` makes them just concatenated.

result:

```
        bill            qty_left
sku     
01-04   {50469}         0
01-20   {50460, 50262}  26
```

If you want a string instead of a set for bill you can use:

```
df2.bill.apply(lambda s: ', '.join(list(map(str, s))))
```

Where `df2` is the result of the `groupby.agg` function above.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with lambda function for remove duplicates in original ordering:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('sku', as_index=False)
         .agg({'bill': lambda x:','.join(dict.fromkeys(x)), 
               'qty_left':'sum'}))
print (df1)
     sku         bill  qty_left
0  01-04        50469         0
1  01-20  50262,50460        26
```

If `bfill` column are strings use:

```
df1 = (df.astype({'bill':str})
         .groupby('sku', as_index=False)
         .agg({'bill': lambda x:','.join(dict.fromkeys(x)), 
               'qty_left':'sum'}))
print (df1)
     sku         bill  qty_left
0  01-04        50469         0
1  01-20  50262,50460        26
```